# Magento 2 TTFB get higher after few hours

Tags: performance, magento, magento2, pagespeed

Hello I am working in magento 2.2.3 I have an issue with `TTFB`. Generally its normal(`0.6s`) but from early morning or `mid night` its increase to `2.5s+`.

Then I have to clear `configuration cache` to `reduce` TTFB to 0.6s.

It is strange but true. I have to clear cache to reduce TTFB then again after night its increasing to 2.5s+

```
So I need to clear cache daily to reduce TTFB and website speed.
```

I checked many things and links but could not get any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2):

Check the allocated disk space of your server, if the cache is filling up without any sufficient storage capacity, it can become a problem very fast.

Second thing but unlikely if you solve the problem by cleaning up the cache, if you see that the problem occurs constantly at the same hours, you should check for the crons running at this time. Re-indexers can be pretty heavy on the website.

Comment: Thank @OddBrew. No there is no issue of disk space. The space is enough. And no any cron is running. Yes reindex process is running but it is in cron that runs every hour.